# How to setx without expanding variables?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to set a variable to a value without expanding that variable. E.g.,

```
setx var1 "%nested_var%\dir"
```

The result is that var1 gets assigned the expanded string, while I'd rather it didn't contain expanded variables. I've tried a number of approaches without results.

Note that this is done on the command line, not in a batch file.

Comment: So you want `var1` to literally expand to `%nested_var%\dir`? The following uses carats (the cmd escape character) to do that - `set var1=^%nested_var^%\dir`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the command from command prompt, then you can use escape character `^`, but you have to remove the quotations, otherwise it will include escape character to variable.

The command would be `setx var1 ^%nested_var^%\dir`

From the batch you leave the quotation marks and you can escape variable expansion by doubling percentage character.

In the batch use `setx var1 %%nested_var%%\dir` or `setx var1 "%%nested_var%%\dir"`

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 -- This solved my SSH-related problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/1101878/windows-to-windows-ssh-get-remote-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

N.B. If one is using setx command from command prompt, the inner environment variables must not be expanded and environment variable has spaces, then use syntax like this:

`setx var1 ^"^%nested_var^%\some dir^"`